# add new field using data multiple $lookup

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, express

Hi i want to concat multiple lookup data value and add a new field by concating
below is my sample collections

```json
db={
  "story": [
    {
      "lang": "E",
      "news_type": "GENERAL",
      "small_heading": " Look After His Family And Party",
      "category_id": "6496a6b7642cd78defff4f4b",
      "subcategory_id": "6496a72a642cd78defff4f58",
      "prefix": "6496a920642cd78defff4fe8",
      "slug": "look-after-his-family-and-party",
      "sticker": "6496a947642cd78defff4ff3",
      
    }
  ],
  "stickers": [
    {
      "_id": "6496a947642cd78defff4ff3",
      "name": "Test Sticker 1",
      "slug": "test-sticker"
    },
    
  ],
  "prefixes": [
    {
      "_id": "6496a920642cd78defff4fe8",
      "name": "Test prefix 1",
      "slug": "test-prefix"
    },
    
  ],
  "category": [
    {
      "_id": "6496a6b7642cd78defff4f4b",
      "name": "category 1",
      "slug": "test-category"
    },
    
  ],
  "subcategory": [
    {
      "_id": "6496a72a642cd78defff4f58",
      "name": "sub category 1",
      "slug": "test-sub-category"
    }
  ],
}
```

and below is my aggregation query.

```js
db.story.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      lang: "E",
      slug: "look-after-his-family-and-party",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "category",
      localField: "category_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            slug: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "categoryDetail"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "subcategory",
      localField: "subcategory_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            slug: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "subCategoryDetail"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "stickers",
      let: {
        sticker_id: "$sticker"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$sticker_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            background_color: 1,
            text_color: 1,
            font_style: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "stickerData"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "prefixes",
      let: {
        prefix_id: "$prefix"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$prefix_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "prefixData"
    }
  },
  
])
```

this is the response that i am getting from the above aggregation query.

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "categoryDetail": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a6b7642cd78defff4f4b",
        "name": "category 1",
        "slug": "test-category"
      }
    ],
    "category_id": "6496a6b7642cd78defff4f4b",
    "lang": "E",
    "news_type": "GENERAL",
    "prefix": "6496a920642cd78defff4fe8",
    "prefixData": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a920642cd78defff4fe8",
        "name": "Test prefix 1"
      }
    ],
    "slug": "look-after-his-family-and-party",
    "small_heading": " Look After His Family And Party",
    "sticker": "6496a947642cd78defff4ff3",
    "stickerData": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a947642cd78defff4ff3",
        "name": "Test Sticker 1"
      }
    ],
    "subCategoryDetail": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a72a642cd78defff4f58",
        "name": "sub category 1",
        "slug": "test-sub-category"
      }
    ],
    "subcategory_id": "6496a72a642cd78defff4f58"
  }
]
```

i need a new complete_slug added by concating category slug, sub-category slug and slug as mentioned below

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "categoryDetail": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a6b7642cd78defff4f4b",
        "name": "category 1",
        "slug": "test-category"
      }
    ],
    "category_id": "6496a6b7642cd78defff4f4b",
    "lang": "E",
    "news_type": "GENERAL",
    "prefix": "6496a920642cd78defff4fe8",
    "prefixData": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a920642cd78defff4fe8",
        "name": "Test prefix 1"
      }
    ],
    "slug": "look-after-his-family-and-party",
    "small_heading": " Look After His Family And Party",
    "sticker": "6496a947642cd78defff4ff3",
    "stickerData": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a947642cd78defff4ff3",
        "name": "Test Sticker 1"
      }
    ],
    "subCategoryDetail": [
      {
        "_id": "6496a72a642cd78defff4f58",
        "name": "sub category 1",
        "slug": "test-sub-category"
      }
    ],
    "subcategory_id": "6496a72a642cd78defff4f58"
  },
  "complete_slug": 'test-category/test-sub-category/look-after-his-family-and-party',
]
```

can some help me out with aggregation query.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `$concat` operator to combine the values from the three fields mentioned into a string.

```
{
  $set: {
    complete_slug: {
      $concat: [
        {
          $first: "$categoryDetail.slug"
        },
        "/",
        {
          $first: "$subCategoryDetail.slug"
        },
        "/",
        "$slug"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/juz5UmeMqEl)

Comment: Another approach is working with `$reduce`. For this approach will allow you to handle in case any field value might be null. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WZSoRLpkwrl)